# Build docker image in C programm

Tags: c, sockets, docker

I am sending over a socket a Dockerfile and a .c file. I am trying to
build the image in a C programm using the following command:

```
system("docker build -t my_image .")
```

But when it starts to build the image, I get the following output:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM gcc:4.9
 ---> 1b3de68a7ff8
Step 2/6 : COPY . /home/server/src
 ---> 3ad55a5751dd
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /home/server/src
 ---> Running in 8d768eda43ee
Removing intermediate container 8d768eda43ee
 ---> bf9a9ff0273b
Step 4/6 : EXPOSE 9000
 ---> Running in 75c48b8aa200
Removing intermediate container 75c48b8aa200
 ---> b38c514453e0
Step 5/6 : RUN gcc ./rand_gen_server.c -o server_side
 ---> Running in b4486ecd8451
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The command '/bin/sh -c gcc ./rand_gen_server.c -o server_side' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

When building directly in the cmd, everything works. I am running the C 
programm using `sudo`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does running `/bin/sh -c gcc ./rand_gen_server.c -o server_side` from the appropriate directory not produce errors?

Comment: Hard to tell since no one knows your Dockerfile or environment. I guess that you have different PATH/other variables when you run your program, but this is only a guess. I would also recommend that you don't run gcc during docker build, but run it before and COPY the result into the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of @ForceBru and @Rudi help me. Since the Dockerfile was obtained from a socket, I had to replace the `COPY` and `WORKDIR` paths to the ones corresponding to the new host.

Also, I changed the step 5/6 to `gcc -c /rand_gen_server.c -o server_side`.

Let's see if the rest of the endeavor will work.

**UPDATE**
Turns out, during compilation, I cannot compile another .c file. In order to do this, I have to create a new process. Using the function `fork()` and the executing the system call for building the docker image did the job. Plus, I did not use the `-c` option during the compilation.